# Difference between unicode 0001 and 2401?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, utf-16, utf

I am trying to use the SOH character as a delimiter for a CSV file that my code generates. However, it looks like there are two unicode characters for SOH?
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2401

https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0001

I am not sure what is the difference between the two is? or which one should I use?

Comment: The standard for SOH is `0x0001`, which is ASCII char 1. However, typically SOH is not used as a delimiter in Unicode. Not sure why you'd be using it at all in that manner. Just out of curiosity, why are you? CSV is `Comma Separated Values`, which means that the standard delimiter is the comma.

Comment: Hint: look at what block U+2401 is in.

Comment: @KenWhite In the OP's defence, it's not all that clear-cut. Many CVS formats use a semicolon for a separator.

Comment: @MrLister: Yep, I've seen a semicolon (although strictly speaking it is no longer a .CSV file, but is simply a delimited text file instead). I have never seen SOH (Char(1)) used as a delimiter in what is supposed to be a file full of printable text, however. SOH was typically used for mainframe terminal and modems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

U+0001 is the control character. U+2401 is a symbolic picture of the character.

Example: ␁ (May not display in all browsers, but is a single pictograph of `SOH`)